# How security vulnerabilities of Android Studio affects development/developer or end-user of the android app?

Tags: android, security, android-studio

How does the security vulnerability of Android Studio affects anything?

[image: Android Studio update prompt]

Comment: This is the Android Studio G+ post, with a link to the JetBrains/IntelliJ posting: https://plus.google.com/103342515830390186255/posts/5TGKhcwtip5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily, it affects the users of Android Studio. Just because you are a computer programmer does not somehow make you magically safe from security issues.

It is theoretically possible that an exploit could somehow cause Android Studio to cause harm to users of apps created via an exploited Android Studio installation. That would be a complex exploit, and there are simpler ways to accomplish the same results.